# There was an error deserializing the object of type: Unexpected end of file

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, soapui

I use soapui to mock a wcf service to get a response, but I just got the error

> There was an error deserializing the object of type: Unexpected end of file.Following elements are not closed: Token,....

I think it is wrong in xml at here

```
            <nsb:Token>"r$1SEdfuY&(r97*9U(_N0uBIdsfb76t7eeD-%^*V(EdOG9pNH)<9_G6"</nsb:Token>
```

Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's invalid XML:

```
    <nsb:Token>"r$1SEdfuY&(r97*9U(_N0uBIdsfb76t7eeD-%^*V(EdOG9pNH)<9_G6"</nsb:Token>
                                                                  ^----
```

the indicated `<` should be at least a `&gt;`, or the whole contents of the `<nsb:token>` inside a cdata block.

Comment: &gt or &lt, what is a cdata block? I used &lt, but it is wrong again.